# How to return the result of a retrofit get request function to a mutable variable

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit

I'm following this tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzbTCLnPR24&list=PLEGrY4uRTu5mn5Hky0xTZS3gK4TbYM_CR&index=1, but the instructor becomes confusing towards the end. I have replicated the code exactly in a separate program, and it worked fine. Now, I am attempting to change the variable names and add a `NavController` to suit my project. However, the mutable variable name turns red inside the function. When I passed a variable as a parameter to the function to check if the code works, it did. However, I am unable to assign the return parameter to the mutable variable.

The `Log.i("Tag", "$user")` returns:
`User(username=Jack, email="Odb@gmail.com")`
where `User` is a data class in a separate file.

In the tutorial, around the 30:10 mark, the instructor doesn't return a value; instead, he assigns `response.body()` to the mutable variable, adds `.value` after it, and it automatically updates a text field.

In my function, the mutable variable isn't even recognized. How can I make this work?

```
@Composable
fun PlayScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    context: Context = LocalContext.current,

){
    var user by remember{mutableStateOf(User("",""))}
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom

    ) {
        Text(text = "$user")
        Button(onClick = {

            getRequest(context)
        }) {
            Text("Getuser")
        }
        
        
    }
}

@Composable

@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun PlayScreenPreview(){
    PlayScreen(
        navController = rememberNavController()
    )
}
fun getRequest(context: Context) { 
    
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        
        val response = try{
            RetrofitInstance.api.getUser("Jack")
        }catch(e: HttpException){
           
            return@launch
        }catch(e: IOException){
            
            
            return@launch
        }
        
        if(response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null){
           
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                user = response.body()!! <------User is red
                Log.i("Tag", "$user") <------Here too

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Ideas about what might be wrong are also welcomed.
Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the `user` variable inside `getRequest()` because it's defined in `PlayScreen()`, and hence is only visible within `PlayScreen()`. What you can do instead is return the result from `getRequest()`:

```
fun getRequest(context: Context): User? { 
    
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        
        val response = try{
            RetrofitInstance.api.getUser("Jack")
        }catch(e: HttpException){
           
            return@launch
        }catch(e: IOException){
            
            
            return@launch
        }
        
        if(response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null){
           
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                return response.body()!!    
            }

        } else {
          return null
        }
    }

}
```

And assign the return value to the `user` variable inside `PlayScreen()`:

```
Button(onClick = {

    user = getRequest(context)
}
```

Note that this code will likely not compile as is, as you'll need to make sure you always return some value from `getRequest()`, but hopefully it demonstrates the idea.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I made the changes but I get a mistake when I assign the result to the mutable variable. It asks to remove the ? of user in the function declaration. And the return statement of the if must be return@withContext response.body()!!, the else must be return@launch, and I need to add a return null before the last } to not have mistakes. If I remove the ?, I get asked to put it back at the return function at the end.

Comment: Yep, you'll need to figure out nullability. `getRequest()` should probably return `User?`, as there's no guarantee that the network request succeeds and you'll need to be able to return null if that happens. Hence, you'll need to adjust the code inside `PlayScreen()` to deal with the nullable `User?` type.

Comment: But how? I get into a circular argument. This line  user = getRequest(context) doesn't want a null argument (user being the mutable variable). the code inside the function is okay with the null variable. It's when I call the function  the problem

Comment: You'll likely need to specify nullability explicitly in this declaration: `var user by remember{mutableStateOf<User?>(User("",""))}`.

Comment: I'm still at the same place I started. the network call is asynchronous returning a value doesn't work. The assignment to the mutable variable must be done inside the function, like in the tutorial.